# PHP scrape multiple pages on a website using cURL that return values only after submitting a form

Tags: php, curl

A website has 250 products and i need to get the quantity for those products. The problem is that the quantity is not displayed unless i submit a form. Now i am able to submit that form but the problem is that after 10-20 products scraped there is like a bottleneck where that website returns this message:

```
Sorry, we have too many customers, please come back later.
```

So basically it's clear that i'm sending too many requests. But if i'm using a `usleep` between requests the time for the **scrape** is like 15 minutes...i guess the server is delaying the answer to my requests.

So basically my question is: what can i do to submit that form without getting stopped or delayed?

Comment: make a cron job that processes the next product every 15 minutes.
but it'd be easier to ask the website owner for an api if you wanna work with his data

Comment: Won't accept, too conservative, any other idea on what i could do?(also i need the products rescraped each hour so one each 15 mins won't do it :(

Comment: That might be because they use something like cookie or some hidden fields in the form with values that they check, you may dig a bit more in the http request and response to find out how they can detect your requests.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically my question is: what can i do to submit that form without getting stopped or delayed?

have your own local cached copy of all the products, and have a daemon or cronjob that is constantly (but slowly) updating your own local cache, which should make your cache as close to up-to-date as possible without hitting the rate limit. and whenever you need to quickly inspect all 250 products, use your own local cache, not the live version. PS: the rate-limit is probably on a per-ip basis, if the update speed of 1 IP is insufficient, you can probably just keep adding more IPs for the cache-updater until the cache update speed is acceptable.. (.. and if you're looking for a cheap place to get more IP's, i can recommend https://cloudatcost.com/developer-cloud - or if you're looking for something free, you can try the torproject https://www.torproject.org/ - but many websites blocks tor exit nodes)